# how do I set a turtle to an image

Tags: image, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I am trying to set my image to a file, but when i run it i get

> Exception in Tkinter callback Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File
>   "C:\Users\Travi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\tkinter__init__.py",
>   line 1699, in **call**
>       return self.func(*args)   File "C:\Users\Travi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\turtle.py",
>   line 686, in eventfun
>       fun()   File "C:\Users\Travi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\RPG.py",
>   line 20, in up
>       combat()   File "C:\Users\Travi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\RPG.py",
>   line 57, in combat
>       enemy.shape(image)   File "C:\Users\Travi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\turtle.py",
>   line 2777, in shape
>       self.turtle._setshape(name)   File "C:\Users\Travi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\turtle.py",
>   line 2506, in _setshape
>       self._item = screen._createimage(screen._shapes["blank"]._data)   File
>   "C:\Users\Travi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\turtle.py",
>   line 723, in _createimage
>       return self.cv.create_image(0, 0, image=image)   File "", line 1, in create_image   File
>   "C:\Users\Travi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\tkinter__init__.py",
>   line 2483, in create_image
>       return self._create('image', args, kw)   File "C:\Users\Travi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\tkinter__init__.py",
>   line 2474, in _create
>       *(args + self._options(cnf, kw))))
>   _tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage1" doesn't exist

when I have the file name clearly stated exactly where it is on my pc.

the code

```
import os
from turtle import Turtle,Screen
print(os.getcwd())
os.chdir('C:\\Users\\Travi\\Downloads')
screen.register_shape("Crawfish_attack.gif")
turtle = Turtle()
turtle.setimage("Crawfish_attack.gif")
```

thanks in advance
BTW the link is [here](http://data:image/jpeg;base64,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)
and the rest of the code all works and is not needed to be shown

Comment: Is it in a folder called Crawfish_attack in your downloads? Otherwise you need to remove the Crawfish_attack from the end of your os.chdir() argument

Comment: Also, have you tried debugging by printing os.getcwd() after you changed the directory?

Comment: It is in the downloads, and yes

Comment: The picture is in your downloads, or in a "Crawfish_attack" folder in you downloads?

Comment: Plus I get the error at he Os.chdir command.

Comment: Yes the picture is in my downloads

Comment: Remove "\\Crawfish_attack"  from the os.chdir() arguments then. You need to path to the folder it is in, not the file. That is what the register shape function will do is pull the exact file in that folder

Comment: You were getting the error because you were trying to path to something (it was looking for a folder) that does not exist

Comment: just figured that out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `"\\Crawfish_attack"` from the `os.chdir()` arguments. You need to path to the folder it is in, not the file. That is what the `register_shape` function will do is pull the exact file in that folder.

You were getting the error because you were trying to path to something (it was looking for a folder) that does not exist.

```
import os
from turtle import Turtle,Screen
print(os.getcwd())
os.chdir('C:\\Users\\Travi\\Downloads')
screen.register_shape("Crawfish_attack.gif")
```

Comment: almost works, but I get a new error when I try to set the image to a turtle

Comment: It's best not to completely edit questions and ask new ones on the same post -- confusing for those coming in the future to see the question and wonder why all the answers don't match up. Please ask a new question regarding new additions you are making to your code and leave this one as is

Comment: then I will ask a new one